# Linux installation stuck at the start up because of nvidia graphic cards

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia

I have a problem with installation of Linux Mint 17 on [Lenova Thinkpad T430](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/t-series/t430/?tt=page1c#techspecs). It has 2 graphic cards nvidia and intel graphic cards. When I try to install it from a bootable disk, it gets stuck at the beginning of the installation. I searched on the web for the solution and found out that nvidia is preventing installation of mint distro. I tried a [solution](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=122257) which seemed to be working in the first case and let me install the Mint alongside Windows 7. Everything was fine until I restart the computer. This time it stocked again at the start up with same problem. When I run in recovery mode of Mint, it gives me an error saying that there is a problem with graphic card driver. I also installed recommended nvidia driver from device driver menu, it did not work.

What can I do to resolve this?

EDIT: Since I have also windows 7, it is not important to disable completely all nvidia functions from computer. When I need nvidia, I can use it on Windows 7. So disabling nvidia also will solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you are a first-time user of Linux, it's preferable to start with Ubuntu, it is more user-friendly and it will let you run the system from the live CD for you to get a taste of it and then choose whether to install it or not. Besides, there's always a good idea to check the distro's HCL (Hardware Compatibility List), in this case Linux Mint has its own:

http://community.linuxmint.com/hardware/search

You have to check exactly the Nvidia graphic card model and make sure that is compatible/supported, for this, you can use the Ubuntu Live CD to start your laptop and once logged in, open a terminal and run the command 'lspci -nn | grep VGA', that will give you the proper graphic card identification. (https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Identification), apart from this you can review some useful documentation at the Ubuntu's site and confirm that the Ubuntu kernel supports this graphic card drivers (it should, and if not, it's under construction).

Comment: I am not first time user of Linux however not experienced though. I will try what you suggest and let you know result.